# Additional drivers page shows nothing at all. (Not an nVidia problem)

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 because before the additional drivers page showed absolutely nothing. During the new install, I made sure to click install 3rd party software (I hadn't clicked this last time and thought that might be the problem).

However, when I was trying to connect to my wifi it didn't work (because of my router only allowing 5 people on at a time), so I said don't connect now. I planned to connect later and install the 3rd party software (what I assume contains the list for proprietary drivers).

Is there any way to get my list of "additional drivers" to show something? I thought maybe I could install updates and get it to work (but that didn't work last time.. But last time I also hadn't checked install 3rd party software..). I don't want to install updates if it won't work because my Internet is pretty slow.

Also, I have it set to check for updates once a day, but if updating is the solution then how do I choose to check for updates now instead of waiting for later?

If doing another reinstall of Ubuntu with wifi working is the solution then I'll be more than happy to do that. Someone please point me in the right direction!

Thanks

Edit1: I figured out how to check for updates immediately. I went to the top left on the unity taskbar and clicked the Dash Home icon. Typed in "software" and "software updater" popped up. That lets you install software updates immediately.

Also, when I looked into Ubuntu's software update settings, the box for installing proprietary drivers was checked, so hopefully this update will also get me the list of drivers. I'll edit again when the update is finished.

Edit2: The updates have finished installing and I restarted my computer, but there are still no options listed in the additional drivers menu. Does anyone know what I can do to see some optional drivers? I have an ATI HD 4200 in my laptop that I would really like the graphics drivers for.

Comment: Check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx But be on a look-out what you are doing!

Comment: Still having this problem? Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue trying to fix a graphics driver problem causing Ubuntu to crash upon login. Solved it by accident! I attempted to install some language updates, then went to the Software and Updates tab and tried to click X to close out of frustration. It then asked me to update, I accepted and upon reentering the list appeared. Try installing and update in general and try closing the tab to see if it asks you. Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The OP appears to have already tried this solution: "The updates have finished installing and I restarted my computer, but there are still no options listed in the additional drivers menu." So while this may be valuable for other, related problems, unfortunately I don't think this is really answering the question asked here.